# 405(Method not Allowed) DELETE

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, restful-url

The problem is like this: Spring RESTful web service, and a client. When performing a DELETE request on the server i get
 -> `DELETE http://localhost:8080/employee/3/logout 405 (Method Not Allowed)`

I have implemented the CORS filter and it stil does not work.

EmployeeCotroller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee")
public class EmployeeController {
    private static final EmployeeRepository employeeRepository = new EmployeeRepository();
public EmployeeController(){
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{employeeId}")
public ResponseEntity<EmployeeDTO> showEmployeeById(@PathVariable int employeeId)
{
    employeeRepository.setEmployeeAsActive(employeeId);
    EmployeeDTO employeeDTO = employeeRepository.getEmployeeDTOForId(employeeId);
    if(employeeDTO != null)
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<EmployeeDTO>(employeeDTO,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<EmployeeDTO>(employeeDTO,HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{employeeId}/viewTasks")
public ResponseEntity<List<TaskDTO>> showTasksForEmployeeId(@PathVariable int employeeId)
{
    List<TaskDTO> taskDTOs = employeeRepository.getTasksForEmployee(employeeId);
    if(taskDTOs != null)
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<TaskDTO>>(taskDTOs, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<List<TaskDTO>>(taskDTOs, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "/{employeeId}/logout}")
public ResponseEntity<Void> logoutEmployeeById(@PathVariable int employeeId)
{
    employeeRepository.logoutEmployeeById(employeeId);
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

}

The place where I make the request:

```
var url = "http://localhost:8080/employee/" + document.cookie1;
$('#employeeLogout').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
           type: "DELETE",
            url: url + "/logout",
            async: true
        });
        document.cookie1 = null;
        window.location.assign('http://localhost:9000/#/employees');
    });
```

Aaand my CORS filter

```
    @Component
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {
    //Web container will call a filter when the request was made.
    // CORS filter allows Cross-Origin requests-responses to be performed by adding Access-Controll-Allow-Origin in the header"
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}
}
```

Comment: Can you post the output that Spring MVC produces on startup and particularly the part where is reports the controller mappings? Thanks

Comment: Instead of giving @requestMapping to controller give it to separate method every time and remove requestMapping from controller.
i.e. for showEmployeeById method  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/employee/{employeeId}")

Comment: Can you give me more specifics about why would I do the @RequestMapping for each method?

Comment: It seems like not any methods besides GET is allowed. When trying with any method besides GET, it produce 405. Any suggestions? btw, i have looked to the output and the right method is mapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a response to this, my problem was on the server-side with the mappings. There was a problem in what the server waited and what the client sent.I was sending the name and the server was waiting for the username. So it was a silly mistake :). If you get random errors be sure to check for foolish mistakes

Answer (score 1):

Same problem I have come through and still struggling a lot to manage. The problem resides somewhere in Spring Security as my code works fine without security. But when spring security is enabled, only GET is allowed, PUT, POST and DELETE don't work.

Comment: you should check your code. there might be something small in the code that you forgot to add. check my answer for details